# Pandas query doesn't work if column contains null values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe containing null values and I want to filter it using `query`

```
data = {'Title': ['Title1', 'Title2', 'Title3', 'Title4'],
        'Subjects': ['Math; Science', 'English; Math', pd.NA, 'English']}

df_test = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df_test)
#     Title       Subjects
# 0  Title1  Math; Science
# 1  Title2  English; Math
# 2  Title3           <NA>
# 3  Title4        English
```

This query gives me an error:

```
df_test.query('Title.str.startswith("T") and Subjects.str.contains("Math")')
```

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/computation/scope.py in resolve(self, key, is_local)
    197             if self.has_resolvers:
--> 198                 return self.resolvers[key]
    199 

36 frames KeyError: 'Series_2_0xe00x4a0x2f0xf50x420x7a0x00x0'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
KeyError: 'Series_2_0xe00x4a0x2f0xf50x420x7a0x00x0'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

UndefinedVariableError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/computation/scope.py in resolve(self, key, is_local)
    209                 return self.temps[key]
    210             except KeyError as err:
--> 211                 raise UndefinedVariableError(key, is_local) from err
    212 
    213     def swapkey(self, old_key: str, new_key: str, new_value=None) -> None:

UndefinedVariableError: name 'Series_2_0xe00x4a0x2f0xf50x420x7a0x00x0' is not defined
```

Same with this query:

```
df_test.query('Title.str.startswith("T") and Subjects.notna() and Subjects.str.contains("Math")')
```

This gives me the desired result

```
df_test[df_test['Subjects'].notna()].query('Title.str.startswith("T") and Subjects.str.contains("Math")')
    Title   Subjects
0   Title1  Math; Science
1   Title2  English; Math
```

I wonder if this is a limitation of `query` or if I'm doing something wrong.

```
pd.__version__
# '1.5.3'
```

Comment: All the queries run for me without giving errors (Python 3.10 and pandas 2.21), maybe this is a problem only in specific versions?

Comment: @ewz93 thanks! I'll check in another environment -- I'm currently on Google Colab

Comment: Can reproduce in Pandas 2.0.3 and Python 3.11 (though the key is different) but not Pandas 2.2.0 and Python 3.12. I guess it was a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Receiving the same error while testing this with `Python 3.10` (`3.10.9` to be exact) and `Pandas 2.2.1`. Somewhat surprising, then, that @ewz93 in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78137513/pandas-query-doesnt-work-if-column-contains-null-values/78137734#comment137753206_78137513) seems to have no issues with these versions.

I can suggest two workarounds:

1. Add [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) before chaining `Series.str.contains("Math")`:

```py
df_test.query('Title.str.startswith("T") and Subjects.fillna("").str.contains("Math")')

    Title       Subjects
0  Title1  Math; Science
1  Title2  English; Math
```

2. Change the engine for [`df.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) from `numexpr` (default) to `python`:

```py
df_test.query('Title.str.startswith("T") and Subjects.str.contains("Math")', 
              engine='python')

    Title       Subjects
0  Title1  Math; Science
1  Title2  English; Math
```

**Note**

In the docs for `df.query`, they advise against passing `engine='python'`, "as it is inefficient compared to using `numexpr` as the engine". All the same, while testing both methods on a `df` with shape `1_000_000, 2)`, method 2 (repeatedly) turned out to be marginally faster:

```
# `fillna` method
573 ms ± 38.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# `engine='python' method
556 ms ± 17.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```